# Rigorously proving that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}d_j$ is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}$

Tags: summation, telescopic-series

The way that I originally arrived upon $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}$ is by seeing that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}d_j$ is similar to a telescoping sum, as when the sums for various values of $k$ are written out a pattern emerges. The following is how I arrived at $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}$:

Take the second sum $\sum_{j=1}^{k}d_j$ and look at a table of the expanded sum for different values of from $1$ to $n$
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
k & \sum_{j=1}^{k}d_j\\
\hline
1 & d_1 \\
2 & d_1+d_2 \\
3 & d_1+d_2+d_3 \\
... & ... \\
n & d_1+d_2+d_3\ +\ ... \ +\ d_n \\
\end{array}
$$
Notice that  $d_1$ appears for every value of $k$ for a total of $n$ times, $d_2$ appears for every value of $k$ after $k=1$ for a total of $n-1$ times, and so on and so forth for every $d_k$ appearing $(n-k+1)$ times ending with $d_n$ appearing once. Therefore the two sums can be written as one which represents how often each $d_k$ appears, specifically $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(n-k+1)d_k$, or in a way that I find cleaner $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}$.

My current problem with my argument is that I feel the introduction of the table and the argument about occurrences isn't very rigorous, is the a more rigorous way I could make my argument? Thanks!

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^{k}d_\color{red}{k}=k \cdot d_k\,$. Did you mean $\,d_\color{red}{j}\,$ there by any chance?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a problem with your argument.  But if you're not happy with it you could always use induction.  The main step would be
$$\eqalign{
  \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^k d_j
  &=\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k d_j\Bigr)
    +\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} d_j\Bigr)\cr
  &=\Bigl(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}\Bigr)
    +\Bigl(\sum_{k=0}^n d_{k+1}\Bigr)\cr
  &=\Bigl(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}+d_{k+1}\Bigr)+d_{n+1}\cr
  &=\sum_{k=0}^n (n+1-k)d_{k+1}\cr}$$
and I'll leave the formal details to you.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind all of it except the transition from $(\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k d_j)$ to $(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)d_{k+1}$. The only reasoning I can come up with is circular.

Comment: Are you familiar with proof by [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)?

Comment: Ah yes, I now understand, that is our assumption, no?

Comment: Yes.  As I said at the end of my answer, I have not given a full proof but am leaving the details for you to write up properly.

Answer (score 2):

> We can transform the double sum of the left-hand side to obtain the right-hand side as follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^kd_j&=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq j\leq k\leq n}}d_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^nd_j\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^nd_j\sum_{k=j}^n1\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^nd_j(n-j+1)\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}d_{j+1}(n-j)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows by replacing in (4) the index $j$ with $k$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the index region in a convenient form to better see what's going on. Then we write the double sum by changing the order of summation.
- In (2) we factor out $d_j$ from the inner sum.
- In (3) we simplify the inner sum.
- In (4) we shift the index by one to start with $j=0$.

Comment: What allows you to do all the 8ndex manipulation and sum order changin in (1)?

Comment: @AaronQuitta: We have finite sums. So, all valid algebraic manipulations are feasible, without necessity of convergence considerations.

Comment: Ok, but *why* are they valid algabraic manipulations?

Comment: @AaronQuitta: Exchanging sums and thereby respecting the index region as done in my answer is finite times an application of the commutative, associative and distributive law. Try it with small $n=2,3$ and expand as intermediate steps the sums to better see what's going on.

Comment: @AaronQuitta: Note also, that the left-hand sum in (1) adds up the terms row-wise while the right-hand sum adds up the terms column-wise with respect to your table,

Comment: Yes thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @AaronQuitta: You're welcome!